# xamarin.forms startactivity xamarin.auth

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

Im trying to use xamarin.auth to loging with facebook, but every tutorial uses 
startactivity(auth.getui(this));

but startactivity doesnt work with me, i cant run it

[Xamarin Android Xamarin.Auth - Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379011/xamarin-android-xamarin-auth-twitter)

he uses it but when i try his code visual studio gives it a red underline:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svk2M.png

I doesnt matter where i put it, it doesnt work, please help.

Comment: StartActivity and startactivity are completely different things.  In C#, casing matters

Comment: You've also typo'd "StartActivity" in your screenshotted example.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the parameters but you can use:

```
Forms.Context.StartActivity (Intent... or Forms.Context);
```