# Twitter Login not redirecting back to app OR auth.Completed not getting called in Xamarin

Tags: twitter, xamarin.ios, twitter-login

After entering login details(real account login details) twitter is opening its own login page and not redirecting to my app "After login page". I have found that 'auth.Completed' is not getting called.

I have used same code(below) for Facebook login with 'OAuth2Authenticator', which works perfect. Found many other developer faced these problem but none provided related answer.

Below all URI is just as you get when you register app for twitter login, but I don't have enough credit to add links below.

```
var auth = new OAuth1Authenticator(consumerKey: "MyAppKey", consumerSecret:    "MyAppSecret", requestTokenUrl: new Uri(""), authorizeUrl: new Uri(""), accessTokenUrl: new Uri(""), callbackUrl: new Uri("http://mobile.twitter.com"));

        auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
        //  this.DismissViewController(true, null);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Is user authenticated" + eventArgs.IsAuthenticated);


            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("method should be invoked.");

                App.Instance.SaveToken(eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]);

                App.Instance.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();


            }
            else 
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Not Authenticate");

                //this.DismissViewController(true, null);
            }
        };


        PresentViewController(auth.GetUI(), true, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a duplicate of [Xamarin Android Xamarin.Auth - Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379011/xamarin-android-xamarin-auth-twitter).

Try changing your callback URL to: http://mobile.twitter.com/home.  Also, in your `Completed` callback, use `oauth_token` instead of `access_token` for the property. `access_token` is only for OAuth2.

Comment: hi there I have previously check that duplicate question but its solution still not redirecting back to my app. Also, I changed my callback URL to your suggested one but no difference, its still going to twitter login page, even after auth login..I just cant figure out whats wrong ..I have done as suggested in other examples available online but found no one ever found answer to it.